# How do I construct a Density Matrix corresponding to a Hamiltonian?

Tags: quantum-state, programming, density-matrix, hamiltonian-simulation

I have a Hamiltonian and I want to know the corresponding density matrix. The matrix I'm interested in is the one in [this question](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/4306/why-is-this-hamiltonian-matrix-diaongal/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's many different density matrices that can correspond to a given Hamiltonian.

---

For the 8x8 matrix in your question, there's 8 different "eigenstate" density matrices that can be obtained, one for each of the 8 eigenvectors. The density matrices are constructed by doing the outer product of the eigenvectors. For the $i^{\rm{th}}$ eigenstate of the Hamiltonian, the density matrix $\rho_i$ is:

$
\rho_i = |\psi_i\rangle_ \langle \psi_i|
$.

---

A system can also be in a "pure" superposition of eigenstates, for example:

$|\psi \rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}|\psi_1\rangle + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}|\psi_2\rangle $.

Then the density matrix is once again made by doing the outer product of the pure wave function $|\psi\rangle$ with itself.

---

A system can also be in a "mixed" state, which means it's a linear combination of "pure" states.

In this case you would construct the density matrix like this (for example):

$\rho = 0.5 \rho_1 + 0.5\rho_2$,

which descrbes a state which is a 50% mixture of $\rho_1$ and a 50% mixture of $\rho_2$.

Comment: Thanks a mil thats very helpful. So what you're saying is I need to construct all 8 density matrixes, add them together to get the sum density matrix?

Comment: It depends what you need the density matrix for :)

Comment: I need it to get the purity of my qubit states and the internal energy of the system vs. the magnetisation factor h

Comment: The Hamiltonian doesn't tell you the state of the system. It just tells you how the current state of your system changes with respect to time.

Answer (score 9):

Your question remains very unclear as to what it actually is that you want to calculate.

There is no direct correspondence between a system Hamiltonian and the quantum state of the system. No matter what the Hamiltonian, any quantum state is a valid state of the system.

Where a Hamiltonian comes in useful is, if you know the state at some time (say, $t=0$), you can find out what the state is at any later time via the Schroedinger equation
$$
i\frac{\partial |\psi\rangle}{\partial t}=H(t)|\psi\rangle.
$$
If $H$ does not change in time, you get
$$
|\psi(t)\rangle=e^{-iHt}|\psi(0)\rangle
$$
or, if your initial state is a mixed state,
$$
\rho(t)=e^{-iHt}\rho(0)e^{iHt}.
$$

Now, there are two reasonable things that *might* be relevant in terms of a state derived from a Hamiltonian - the thermal state and the ground state (which is the thermal state at 0 temperature). At temperature $T$, the thermal state is
$$
\rho_{\text{thermal}}=\frac{e^{-H/(k_BT)}}{\text{Tr}(e^{-H/(k_BT)})},
$$
while the ground state is simply the eigenstate of $H$ with the smallest energy. You can (crudely) think of the thermal state as the best guess about what the state would be if you cooled it to a temperature $T$.

In one of the comments on another answer, you say

> I need it to get the purity of my qubit states and the internal energy
>   of the system vs. the magnetisation factor h

Purity has nothing to do with the Hamiltonian. If you know the density matrix $\rho$ of your system, purity is just $\text{Tr}(\rho^2)$. The Hamiltonian will help you with the expected internal energy: $\text{Tr}(\rho H)$ but, again, the state has to be provided from elsewhere, not from the Hamiltonian.

Comment: Thank you for the answer that has cleared things up a little more now. I just need to go back and revise my method I think. I will post a solution when I have my code complete I didn't explain it well but I can provide an answer I feel will suffice

Comment: @OisinBrannock It would be better if you could work a bit more on the question to make it clear what it is you're after. An answer is far more relevant once people understand the question.

Comment: Yeah cool I'll work on the question it is a bit all over the place to be fair thanks for the feedback

Comment: @DaftWullie: I think the question is completely fine the way it is. "What is the density matrix corresponding to a given Hamiltonian?" the answer is that when the system has Hamiltonian H, there's many different $\rho$ that are valid. I've given some examples and you've given 2 examples. Not any density matrix is okay (for example if the size is different from the size of the Hamiltonian).  Further questions about the user's problem can be asked in a new question.

Comment: Look, the question the way it is right now, is not too surprising for a beginner. I think a lot of people will have the same question over the coming years. I can't remember but I think I also might have been confused about the relationship between Hamiltonian and state when I was in the very early stages. I think the question can be left how it is, and further questions about the user's goals can go in a new question.

Comment: @user1271772 *Not any density matrix is okay (for example if the size is different from the size of the Hamiltonian)."* -- Not even that need to be the case. Consider, e.g. the density matrix for the thermofield double of the thermal state of H. -- I have to say I agree with DaftWullie that the question is too fuzzy, so it is impossible to provide a clear answer. It would have been better to ask "What are possible ways to derive density operators from Hamitonians?"  Though I suspect that the OP has something more specific in mind -- but it is hard to guess this from a question of  2 lines.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch: what is a thermofield double? The density matrix as to be the same size as the hamiltonian because $\rho(t) = e^{-iHt}\rho(0)e^{iHt}$ for time-independent Hamiltonians.

Comment: @user1271772 This assumes that "the density matrix corresponding to a Hamiltonian" is a density matrix on which the Hamiltonian acts by time evolution - fully, not only for part of it.  This is no-where said in the question.

Comment: @user1271772 Thermofield double = purification of a Gibbs state. Very well a natural state arising from a Hamiltonian.

Comment: I don't really know what "purification of a Gibbs state" is, and I have never heard of a thermofield double before, and there's not much online about it. Generally when I see a density matrix and I want to know how it evolves, I think of a Hamiltonian matrix of the same size. Perhaps one Hamiltonian can help you generate a density matrix of double the size, but then there will be another Hamiltonian the size of the density matrix which can be used to evolve the bigger density matrix.

Comment: @user1271772 (You need to use @...) Let $|\psi\rangle=(e^{-\beta H}\otimes I)(\sum_i |i,i\rangle)$. This is  a purification of the Gibbs state (i.e. $e^{-\beta H}$), an object which is quite useful - for simulation of thermal states, in quantum gravity (where they call it thermofield double), ... .  Doesn't live in a space of the same dimension!

Comment: I don't understand the $\sum_i |i,i>$ part. Anyway, I gave 3 examples of density matrices you can construct from a Hamiltonian, and DaftWulie gave another (the thermal state), and you have given now another one (the thermofield state). There's nothing wrong with this as far as I can see. Perhaps my statement that rho and H must be the same size is not 100% correct. I could change it, but at this point it doesn't seem I'll gain anything out of that. The main point is that several different rho can be generated from one H, and OP thought (but not anymore) that there was a 1-to-1 correspondence.

Comment: The ground state and the thermal state are *meaningful* examples. Arbitrary superpositions or mixtures of eigenstates are *arbitrary* examples, except for the fact that they can be multiplied with the Hamiltonian and are positive semidefinite.